# Python configparser somehow duplicates options in source file

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, configparser

So what I am trying to do is get options from configfile1 and write them to configfile2, simple.

This works great if it would not be for the fact that somehow stuff gets changed in configfile1. After I use the parser to write to file2 somehow options in file1 are duplicated.

Initializing of the parser:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
```

Here is the code:

```
def parseOptions(self):
    self.parser.clear()
    self.parser.read(sourceQgisIniFile)
    toBeImportedDictionary = dict(self.parser.items('qgis'))
    toBeImportedDictionary = dict(filter(lambda item: 'test' in item[0], toBeImportedDictionary.items()))

    self.parser.clear()
    self.parser.read(targetQgisIniFile)

    for dataSource in toBeImportedDictionary:
        self.parser.set('qgis', dataSource, toBeImportedDictionary[dataSource])

    with open(targetQgisIniFile, 'w') as qgisconf:
    self.parser.write(qgisconf)
```

The source file in `/home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini`

and target in `/home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/test/QGIS/QGIS3.ini`

I tried using two parsers, one for each file but that did not work.